# Golang for each filtering into a new var

Tags: go, variables, foreach, var

Im working with for each loop and var of information and filtering it by A) regex.matchString B)Timecomparrison. The filtering works well and I have the data I need but currently I'm outputting it to screen via fmt.Println in part of the loop. My goal is to take that data and build another var with the now filtered list. I guess I need to make a new variable and add to it? But how do I return that and something I can use later?

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
   for _, thing := range things {
 
       if thing.element1 != nil {
 
           matched, err := regexp.MatchString(z, element1)
 
           if err != nil {
               fmt.Println(err)
           }
 
           if matched {
 
               if timecomparrison(element2, a) {
 
                  
                   // this is a section that needs to be added new var and returned as a var
                   fmt.Println("****")
                   fmt.Println("element1:", element1)
                   fmt.Println("element2:", element2)
 
               }
           }
       }
   }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

```
type Thing struct {
    element1 string
    element2 string
}

func filter() []Thing {
    things := []Thing{
        {element1: "element1", element2: "element2"},
    }
    var result []Thing
    regex := "/{}d/"
    date := time.Now
    for _, thing := range things {
        if thing.element1 != nil {
            matched, err := regexp.MatchString(regex, thing.element1)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            if matched {
                if timeComparison(thing.element2, date) {
                    // this is a section that needs to be added new var and returned as a var
                    fmt.Println("****")
                    fmt.Println("element1:", thing.element1)
                    fmt.Println("element2:", thing.element2)
                    result = append(result, thing)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I cleaned the code, added a type and some data, fixed some issues and renamed some things, but you should get the idea :)

Comment: `filter()` should be passed a `[]Thing` argument instead of having the filter input hard coded.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to keep the code as close as possible to what he had. It would be a simple change :)

Comment: Ultimately this answered my question thank-you